# How to make Wi-Fi visible with OpenWrt 15

Tags: wireless-networking, openwrt

I have successfully created my local network with my router that uses OpenWrt, and my older phones can connect to the Wi-Fi with their passwords.

Now I got a new phone and when I hit *Search for Wi-Fi*...***my own Wi-Fi is not visible***.

This is my Wi-Fi setup:

[OpenWrt Wi-Fi setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojdcB.png)

What should I do to make my Wi-Fi network visible?

Comment: I don't have OpenWrt in front of me. Exactly what options does the width pop-down menu give you? That's the only thing I see that could be suspicious, unless the "Hide ESSID" checkbox is lying to you (you could try setting it, saving, clearing it, and saving again). It would also be interesting to know if setting channel 1 instead of 13 makes a difference. Maybe your older phones are acting like US phones and not supporting channels 12 or 13?

Comment: @Spiff You are right, the channels are the source of the problem. If you promote your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone was unable to find my Wi-Fi because it used *an uncommon channel (13).*

When I changed it to **Channel 8**, it worked okay.